# Is there any (short) way to define the same type for all entries of an object?

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to define the content of an object through TypeScript. All of its entries (key: value) are the same type.

Is there some way to do this that does not require to write all of them?

```
const object: { key1: number; key2: number; key3: number; key4: number, ... } = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3,
  key4: 4
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const obj: { [key: string]: number } = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
    key4: 4
};
```

This will enforce the value type and give an error if doing something like `obj['key5'] = 'Test'`